# Ignore all buffer's local variables

Tags: file-local-variables

Is there any way to open an emacs file so that all local variables definitions are ignored? I often use local variables into `tex` documents to fix root documents, dictionaries, etc. Sometimes I need to compile some document ignoring these variables.

For example, in a TeX document, I have

```lisp
%%  Local Variables: 
%%  TeX-master: t  
%%  End:
```

Sometimes I'd like to ignore that because, for example, I don't want to treat the file as a master file.

Comment: You likely wouldn't actually want to do that.  I think you'd quickly find that *some* of the local variables are quite important, such as `default-directory` and all of your buffer-local minor modes.  I suspect you only need to ignore some subset and that you should target that subset explicitly.  Which variables do you need to ignore, and in which circumstances?  Is it just for `M-x compile`?

Comment: I edited the question explaining what type of variables I would like to ignore

Comment: What you mean are [file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc string of [`enable-local-variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html) says:

> …
> A value of nil means always ignore the file local variables.
> …

You can customize the value of this variable to *Ignore*, open your file and revert the customization.

Then there is also the variable `local-enable-local-variables` which you can use itself as file variable. If you set this variable to `nil` all other file variables are ignored with the exception of a mode specification in a leading `-*- ... -*-` comment at the beginning of the file.